# How to reject access in Spring after successful authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, authorization

I'm implementing some REST services in Spring and need to reject, in some cases, a successful login of a user.

I have implemented my *UserDetailsService* and programmed the *loadUserByUsername(String username)* method, but, when a user gets correctly authenticated, I need to do another validation and, if it fails, reject the access.

To do so I have implemented a listener to detect correct authentications:

@Component
public class LoginSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener{
    @Autowired
    LicenseControlService licenseControlService;

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent  e){
    User user = (User)e.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    //Here I want to reject the access because of whatever logic 
}
```

I need to be sure to apply the logic which might reject the access when the user gets correctly authorized, that's why I need to put the logic when I receive this event.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The `UserDetailsService` is used for authentication purposes only. What you're talking about appears to be authorization (checking if someone is authorized to access a webpage for example). Please explain by which criteria you want to reject someone. That makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: The thing is... I need to validate that the users logged in don't exceed a certain amount of users. So I thought of this solution I explained because I dont know a new user logged in until I get the event fired (the _onApplicationEvent_). My idea was to validate there but, I would have to be able to reject the user if he/she is exceeding the limit of users logged

Comment: If you're able to keep track of users that are currently logged in, I would probably set the user to disabled in the `UserDetailsService`. Check [`UserDetails.isEnabled()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#isEnabled--).

Comment: I have tried what you said and it is denying the access to the user (that's what I wanted), but spring is returning a 401. I would like to customise the response, so the client knows why he is being rejected... is that possible?
What I did was, at the class which implements the _UserDetailsService_, when returning the User class, instantiate it with a _false_ at the _enabled_ property... that returns a 401 to the requester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im posting the solution I have adopted in case someone needs the same behaviour:

What I did was, at the class which implements the UserDetailsService, when returning the User class, instantiate it with a false at the enabled property... that returns a 401 to the requester.

I also implemented a CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint which extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint, and with an overriden comence method. That method is called whenever Spring is returning an authentication error, so, in this method, I can query the type of the AuthenticationException and decide and modify the returned status according to it.